# AngularJS: refresh ng-include depending on parameter

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to refresh an ng-include asking it to refetch the template from server?
i know i can remove the entry from the `$templateCache` via, `$templateCache.remove('/templates/home')`. but really ask the div to refresh the ng-include and thus repload it from the server.

usecase: apart from all other templates the home template is different whether you are logged in or not. it is so different that it is a separate template on the server. however it resides on the same route, the root of the app.

yet after a user refreshes the screen it loads the correct template, but when a user is logging in, the ng-include doesn't refresh. That is what i'm trying to fix.

but just emptying the templateCache does not fix this. as the view is not actually refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

technically not an answer to the question but we solved our situtation by not serving 2 templates on 1 url. so when you are logged in we fetch a template from a different url than when you are loggedin. this way you get the loggedin homepage versus the not loggedin homepage.

Answer (score 1):

A rude way to force page refresh is to use $route.reload(). See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route

Comment: somthing i couldn't do because i'm using a custom routing system, however I found a fix which just involves changing the url of the 2 templates, instead of having the server push 2 templates on 1 url, I let the client set the template on a scope variable. and when you include that path from the variable it will re-render when the variable changes. I will sum up the changes i made in an answer soon